# How do I make a JQuery Draggable with a smaller clone?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a large element that is displayed on the screen that I would like to be able to drop on a smaller drop target. Therefore, I want to decrease the size of the draggable clone to match the size of the drop target. I thought it would look nice to animate this. I can't seem to get the smaller clone to center around the cursor while dragging though. Any ideas? Here is a what I tried:
http://jsfiddle.net/a3Cj2/

```
$( ".draggable" ).draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    start : function(event, ui){
        ui.helper.animate({
            width: 80,
            height: 50
        });
    }, 
    drag : function(event, ui){
        ui.helper.offset({
             left: event.pageX,
             top: event.pageY
        });
    }
});

$("#target").droppable({
    drop : function(event, ui) {
       console.log('dropped');     
    }
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simplest approach by far is to use the `cursorAt` option with 'left' and 'top' set to half the dimensions of the shrunken helper.

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    start: function (e, ui) {
        ui.helper.animate({
            width: 80,
            height: 50
        });
    },
    cursorAt: {left:40, top:25}
});
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a3Cj2/2/)**

Comment: This is much more simple, and does the trick. However, it doesn't have quite the same effect of animating the movement to the center.

Comment: @MikeMarcacci, you're right, the shrink effect here is less attractive than in your answer, though the nett result is the same. For me, the big advantage in this approach is that the helper doesn't end up with margins that could possibly be an issue later in some circumstances.

Comment: Yes, I do agree with you on that. If the object gets destroyed once it's dropped then using margins is fine, but if it's going to say around for any time after that, then your solution is a much better idea.

Comment: Thanks guys, both solutions work for me. However, are you actually getting a drop event when you drop in the square? Even if I increase the size of the drop target I am not consistently getting the drop event. I am using Chrome v.26. To be fair, my original fiddle isn't getting the event either, so it is not your additions that are causing it.

Comment: I discovered the 'tolerance' option in the droppable config. I set it to pointer and it works great. I am going to mark the simpler solution as the answer since it worked for me, but both were great approaches. Up voting both.

Answer (score 3):

Wow, that took more work than I thought! Here's the fix:

```
$( ".draggable" ).draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    start : function(event, ui){
        ui.helper.animate({
            width: 80,
            height: 50,
            marginLeft: (300-80)/2 - (300/2 - event.offsetX),
            marginTop: (200-50)/2 - (200/2 - event.offsetY)
        });
    }, 
    drag : function(event, ui){

    }
});

$("#target").droppable({
    drop : function(event, ui) {
       console.log('dropped');     
    }
});
```

You need to account for the event position and center it according to the difference between the centers of both sized draggables.

[See fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mike_marcacci/eJEyP/).

Comment: Note too that I kept the widths and heights in there so you could see what's going on, but `(300-80)/2 - (300/2 - event.offsetX)` could really be simplified to `event.offsetX-40`